# How to use querySelector inside forEach in HTML file of LWC bundle?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, shadow-dom

This might be super easy but I am stuck. I have a lightning card inside forEach on the template. In Javascript, I need to find the card, and add dynamic css based on some business logic. However, querySelector won't let me find the tag in JS. I might be missing something very basic here, any pointers are much appreciated.

**HTML File:**

```
 <template for:each={sampleArray} for:item="item">
        <div key={item.Id}>
                <article class="slds-card" data-id={item.Id}>
                   <p>Some text here</p>
                </article>
        </div>
</template>
```

**JS File :**

```
renderedCallback(){
   //skipping the loop but item.Id has valid value here
    let selectorId = 'article[data-id="' + item.Id + '"]'; 
   
    console.log('selector ->' + selectorId); //returns proper string

    //below line throws run time error, cannot read properties of undefined
    let element = this.template.querySelector('article[data-id="' + item.Id + '"]'); 

    element.classList.add('test-color'); //add different classes as per business logic, keeping it concise here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you missed this out to make the answer brief, but in the `renderedCallback` which Id are you referring to?

You have

```
let element = this.template.querySelector('article[data-id="' + item.Id + '"]');
```

But you should probably have:

```
let element = this.template.querySelector('article[data-id="' + this.sampleArray[0].Id + '"]');
```

Or perhaps you were wanting to add color to them all, in which case you might want to do something like:

```
let elements = this.template.querySelectorAll('article');
elements.forEach( element=>element.classList.add('test-color'); );
```

Comment: This is the same item.Id which is used in HTML template, I just skipped the loop in JS file to keep it brief here. The argument for the querySelector is fine, I have used a console statement to check that. However, it still returns undefined which is making my head spin.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility of that error on this line of code:

```
let element = this.template.querySelector('article[data-id="' + item.Id + '"]');
```

Is that `item` must be `undefined`. If querySelector matched nothing, `element` would be `null`.

`this`, `template`, `querySelector` are all guaranteed to exist and not be `undefined` within a `renderedCallback`.

I even [wrote a little demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/7ZantS1gIr283DBAeaVy/src/app.js?p=stories).

Answer (score 0):

I just copied all your code to my test LWC.
And it works for me .

**Could you please share code where you are iterating in JS file**

This code works for me :
JS :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
const sampleArray = [{Id :'1'},{Id :'2'},{Id :'3'}]

export default class TestArray extends LightningElement {


  sampleArray = sampleArray;

  renderedCallback(){
    console.log('renderedCallback');
    this.sampleArray.forEach((item) => {
        let selectorId = 'article[data-id="' + item.Id + '"]'; 
    
        console.log('selector ->' + selectorId); //returns proper string
    
        //below line throws run time error, cannot read properties of undefined
        let element = this.template.querySelector('article[data-id="' + item.Id + '"]'); 
        console.log(element);
        element.classList.add('test-color'); //add different classes as per business logic, keeping it concise here
    })
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
<template>
  <template for:each={sampleArray} for:item="item">
      <div key={item.Id}>
          <article class="slds-card" data-id={item.Id}>
              <p>Some text here</p>
          </article>
      </div>
  </template>
</template>
```

the css file:

```
.test-color{
  color: red;
}
```

the UI :
[image]

and the JS console.
[image]

```
So I think your problem in Iteratin throw the list in JS file!!
```